# How to format the address in TWIG?

Tags: html, drupal, tags, twig, drupal-8

I have a Drupal site and I want to format the address in TWIG.

How do I delete spaces before and after the address?

How to replace the tags `"<br>"` by `" - "` ?

Here is the TWIG code :

```
<strong>Adresse postale :</strong> {{ store.address }}
```

Here is the rendering :

```
<pre class="text-left"><strong>Raison sociale :</strong> Poupette &amp; Cacahuète.
<strong>Adresse postale :</strong> 
            <div class="field field--name-address field--type-address field--label-hidden field--item"><p class="address" translate="no"><span class="address-line1">rue du vermont</span><br>
<span class="postal-code">14600</span> <span class="locality">Honfleur</span><br>
<span class="country">France</span></p></div>

<strong>Téléphone :</strong> .
<strong>Adresse électronique :</strong> poupette.cacahuete14@gmail.com
<strong>Boutique :</strong> https://www.s1biose.com/fr/boutique/poupette-cacahuete
Immatriculé au  de  sous le numéro .
</pre>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like complete control over the render of this, you can access the individual address 'pieces' by using `store.address.my_value`. So for instance, your address as you described it in a comment would look like:

```
<span class="my-class">
{{ store.address.address_line1 }} - {{ store.address.postal_code }} {{ store.address.locality }} - {{ store.address.country }}
</span>
```

If this is the way you *always* want this to appear, consider adding a **theme override** for the `address-plain.html.twig` template to render this as you would like consistently. You can start by copying the module's template from docroot/modules/contrib/address/templates/address-plain.html.twig and altering it within your theme to be as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/replace.html) and [trim](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/trim.html) functions like this:

```
{{ store.address|trim|replace({'<br>': '-'})|raw  }}
```

Comment: The output of `replace` is not marked as safe, so u'd need to apply the filter `raw` as well

Comment: @DarkBee, your comments are better than my answer, so create your answer and I delete mine and I vote for yours :)

Comment: @doydoy44 My comments are not correct. In the first, the markup is rendered in plain text, in the second there is no rendering. Here is what I want to render : `rue du vermont - 14600 Honfleur - France`

Comment: @doydoy44 I want to make the address on one line, without markup + by replacing `<br>` with `" - "` + by deleting the spaces before and after.

Comment: @Mathieu do you test the rim function to remose spaces ?

Comment: @doydoy44 what should be the code ? I'm on Drupal with Drupal Commerce in the stores template

Comment: @Mathieu, sorry for bad typo. I would say if you test {{ store.address|trim }} to remove spaces ?

Comment: @doydoy44 If I use `{{ store.address }}` the rendering is the same as in my question. If I insert additional code, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Ok it works with this code `{{ store.address|render|trim|replace({'<br>': ' - '})|raw }}` but I have to remove all the tags to put on a single line (like raw text but with "-").

Comment: `{{ store.address|render|trim|replace({'<br>': ' - '})|striptags|raw }}` I found but there is still a problem, you must put the address on one line https://ibb.co/zfC5Rn8

Comment: Why does it make the field on 3 lines ?

Comment: I guess you have 3 lines in your database. you can use `nl2br` twig function to check that and try something like `|replace({'<br><br>': ' - '})` or `|replace({'<br> <br>': ' - '})` to solve it after `nl2br`

Comment: @doydoy44 Thanks but it doesn't work. I may have a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741391/how-to-make-the-address-code-on-one-line-with-twig