# How to make the address code on one line with TWIG?

Tags: html, drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I have a TWIG code to display the address of a store.

Currently the address is rendered on 3 lines.

How to make the address code on one line ?

```
{{ store.address|render|trim|replace({'<br>': ' - '})|striptags|raw }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are outputting the address inside a `<pre>` tag. The `white-space` of the `<pre>` tag is set to `pre` by default. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for more information about this.

So you have 2 options

1. Replace the `<pre>` tag with a `<div>`

```html
<div>
Lorem
        ipsum
            dolor
                sit
                    amet
</div>
```

2. Overrule the `white-space` of the `<pre>` with `css`

```css
pre.spaceless {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Lorem
    ipsum
        dolor
            sit
                amet
</pre>
<pre class="spaceless">
Lorem
    ipsum
        dolor
            sit
                amet
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this

```
{{ store.address|render|trim|replace({'<br>': ' - ','\n':' ', '\r':' '})|striptags|raw }}
```